# Find the probability for the function $Z = \min\{X,Y\}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be two independent random variables with the cumulative distribution
functions

$F_X(x)= 1−(2/3)^x, x=1,2,3,···;$ and

$G_Y(y)= 1−(3/4)^y, y=1,2,3,\ldots;$ respectively.

Let $Z = \min\{X, Y \}$. Then, the probability $P (Z ≥ 6)$ is $\frac{1}{32}$.
I am getting $\frac{63}{64}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How are you getting $\frac{63}{64}$? Please edit the question to show your work.

Comment: Look at the answer; the derivation there is correct.  You are getting $63/64$ because you are actually computing $P(Z \leq 6)$, not $P(Z \geq 6)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(\min(X,Y)\geq 6)
    & =P(X\geq 6,Y\geq 6) \\
    & =P(X\geq 6)P(Y\geq6) \\
    & = [1-P(X\leq 5)][1-P(Y\leq 5)] \\
    & = [1-F_{X}(5)][1-G_{Y}(5)] \\
    & = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{5}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{5} \\
    & = \frac{1}{2^{5}} \\
    & = \frac{1}{32}
\end{align}

Comment: Fine answer, but it reads nicer if you use the `align` environment.

Comment: @BrianTung can you please edit it ?. Then I can read the code and understand it better. The sites I have looked for aligning in latex and jax are difficult to understand. That is why I always have trouble aligning functions.

Comment: There you go.  Hopefully it should be apparent what I've done.  (I also edited the brackets.)  Feel free to revert it if you prefer your original, but I think it's easier to read this way.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks . I don't have to use $$ then right?. Just start by begin{align} and the n next like by \\ and for each statement start with & like we do in matrices.

Comment: Yes, although I don't pretend to understand *why* the dollar signs aren't needed with the `align` environment.  Maybe a mod can step in and explain that.